# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './' in 'C:\pathToFeeds'

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, visual-studio-code

I know this question has been asked multiple times before, but none of them seem to fit my scenario.

As can be seen from the title, I am getting an error in my application:

Here is the directory structure of my app:

[image]

Here is my **app.module.ts**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FeedsComponent } from './Components/Feeds/feeds.component';
import { StatusComponent } from './Components/Status/status.component';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FeedsComponent,
    StatusComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my **feeds.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'feeds',
    templateUrl: './feeds.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['']
})

export class FeedsComponent {
    public testText: string = 'Feeds Test Text';
}
```

Here is my **status.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'status',
    templateUrl: './status.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['']
})

export class StatusComponent {
    public testText: string = 'Test Status Text';
}
```

I have done the following:

- Updated my angular/cli to the latest.
- Tried using the following in the imports in the **app.module.ts**: `'../app/Components/Status/status.component'`

Why am i getting this error from webbpack when I am trying to serve my application?

Comment: try `../Components/Status/status.component`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, don't know why I always think of these things after I post on Stackoverflow, but I had to remove the following from within the `@Component({})`.

I had to remove the empty `styleUrls: ['']` in both the `feeds.component.ts` and `status.component.ts`.

My component now looks as follow:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'status',
    templateUrl: './status.component.html'
})
```